# Roof Rafter/Beam Joint pulling apart and sagging

Tags: roof, attic, joists, support, joints

There is a joint in my attic where 4 beams or rafters meet. Someone used a 2x4 to support one of the beams, but it did not work because the beam was in two sections.As you can see in the pictures, there is a couple of inches in sag, and the rafters are beginning to pull apart. I was considering putting a 2x6 across the ceiling joists on top of a wall, then hammering in a 2x4 to "jack" up the joists. I am new to this forum and not a construction expert. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
[image: front view]
[image: bottom view]
[image: back view]
[image: alternate bottom view]
[image: top view]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Interesting question, and good work with the documentation; let's see if one of our pros can answer it. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though this thing was built out of scraps pieced together.  There is just no way this is ever going to be sound the way it is.

I think your best course of action is to build some temporary supports to keep the roof from collapsing, pull out the substandard rafters and rebuild using correctly sized lumber, supported properly.

If you're in doubt about how to do this, you may want to hire a professional.  I wish there was some quick and east fix but unfortunately I just don't see that in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I am sure it has been like this since we bought the house (2 years ago). This is why you get a home inspection...

Comment: @Floyd  I'm also noticing all the water staining on these boards.  It's possible that these were present when the structure was built but if this has happened more recently, you have a water leakage problem as well.

Comment: the staining is old. There are several spots like this in the attic. The house was build in the 50s and all of the wood up there is original from what I can tell. Whenever it rains hard I normally go up there and check on things. Normally there is very minor leakage in a couple of spots. The spot in question is not currently leaking.